# Using Cordova ADAL, is it possible to reach to two different API (graph.windows.net and graph.microsoft.com, for azure and office 365) ?

Tags: javascript, adal

Using Cordova ADAL, is it possible to reach to two different API (graph.windows.net and microsoft.com, for azure and office 365) ?

I am trying to use the graph api and reach for information regarding groups tenants etc. 
I would also like to query the microsoft.com, simply to retrieve pictures.

However, using cordova ADAL, I am only able to retrieve token for one of them. Is it possible to get both?

If it's not possible, would it be possible to simply get a code, so the server can ask for both, independantly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

MS-ADAL is using to get authenticate  a particular user , plugin will return a token after successful authentication.
We can authenticate the user in active directory against office 365 products like yammer or our custom API's which are hosted in cloud.
Either you can make a graph API call separately or use some tool to extract the claims from token .

Comment: I already have a token for Graph.windows.net, but it doesn't work for graph.microsoft.com. Is there a way to get a token that can be used for both?

Comment: follow the this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-cordova/ . I can get the O/P